# Copy bin files on to Physical file location on Post Build event in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I want to copy my dll generated in bin folder to a file location on Post Build Event in vs2010.

Can some one help me on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You want to add something like:

```
xcopy /Q /Y "$(TargetPath)" "C:\path\to\somewhere\"
```

to you post-build event on the *Build Events* tab in the project properties page. The `/Y` will stop it from prompting you to confirm an overwrite.

If you also need to copy the `.pdb` file, you will need something like this:

```
xcopy /Q /Y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).*" "C:\path\to\somewhere\"
```

You can see more substitution tokens (the $XXX values) by clicking the *Edit Post-build...* button in the properties tab and then expanding the *Macros>>* button.

Comment: Please tell me the diff between xcopy and copy. Why do we need to do /Q /Y here

Comment: `xcopy` is a more powerful version of `copy` with more options, and hence more control over how things are copied. It is also capable of copying directories. The `/Q` stops the names of the copied files from being written to the output window, and the `/Y` stops it prompting you if it needs to overwrite a file.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the project, then go to Properties->Build Events->Post-build command line.

Then type this in:

```
Cmd /C Copy "$(TargetPath)" "<YourTargetDirHere>"
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

We use the following post build event for copying plugin dlls to the web application's plugin directory:

> copy $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)Convergence.WebApp\home\plugins\$(TargetFileName)

This works across multiple machines where the physical path may be different, but relies upon the destination being relative to the $(SolutionDir).

Answer (score 3):

For those of you that want to copy everything from the Output folder

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*" "C:\testpublish\updater\"  /s /Y
```