# How to change asp .net web service application build path instead of bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am working asp.net web service application.
Normally running time my application dll taken from bin directory.
now i want to add some XML file and folder,so i want to change web service build directory.

I changed directory like this [ex:bin\Common],but this kind of issue came.

**Parser Error**

```
Parser Error Message:** Could not create type 'WebService.MainLogic'.
```

**Source Error:**

```
Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="MainLogic.asmx.cs" Class="WebService.MainLogic" %>
```

**Source File:** /MainLogic.asmx    **Line: 1**

How can I change the directory?

Answer (score 0):

you can copy bin folder to specific folder after build project.

Right Click on project and go to properties => Build Events

in Post-build event command line write below command :

> xcopy /Q /Y "$(TargetPath)" "C:\path\to\somewhere\"

for more information see this link : [Copy bin files on to Physical file location on Post Build event in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664386/copy-bin-files-on-to-physical-file-location-on-post-build-event-in-vs2010)